# How to solve the system made by equations $4a+7/2b+3c=0$ and $a+5b+2c=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How to solve the following system of equations?:

$$\begin{align} 4a+7/2b+3c&=0 \\ a+5b+2c&=0\end{align}$$ I used the Gaussiam elimination and by subtracting the second row by the first one multiplied by $1/4$ I get the two equations $4a+7/2b+3c=0$ and $47/8b+11/4c=0$ which are still not solvable.

Comment: A unique solution to a system of three variables is only possible with three equations.  Three equations in three variables does not guarantee a unique solution, but a system of two equations in three variables is not sufficient to determine whether a unique solution exists, and if it does, what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have fewer equations than unknowns, and so the system does not have a unique solution. It has a one-parameter family of solutions that in this case can be computed by the cross product:
$$(4,7/2,3)×(1,5,2)=(-8,-5,33/2)$$
$$(a,b,c)\in\{(-8t,-5t,33t/2):t\in\mathbb R\}$$

Comment: so when a system has more unknowns than equations it means that it must have more than one solution?

Comment: @user767860 Yes.

Comment: what if it has more equations than unknowns?

Comment: @user767860 Usually no solution, unless some of the equations are redundant.

Comment: for example $4a+7b=0$, $a+3b=0$ and $2a+b=0$ has $a=b=0$ as a solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, $a,b,c$ can be expressed in terms of a parameter (say $k \in \Bbb R$), as we have $3$ variables but only $2$ equations.

$$4a+\frac72b+3c=0$$
$$a+5b+2c=0$$

By cross-multiplication,

$$\frac{a}{7-15}=\frac{b}{3-8}= \frac{c}{20-\frac72} = k \Rightarrow (a,b,c) = \left(-8k,-5k,\frac{33}2k\right)$$